# What's an elegant way to get a Google Blog-esque scrolling header in my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Google has an excellent [blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/) that has a fairly neat header - as you scroll down the gray bar in the header moves up, until it stops when it is at the top of the screen (it also does some fancy z-index tricks but I'm not interested in those).

While I'm aware of CSS's position:fixed, what Google seems to have done is combine position:fixed and position:relative based on the current position of the vertical scroll bar. I guess I would be able to duplicate this behaviour using scroll events, fancy math, and some messy scripted jQuery/CSS, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, elegant, perhaps third-party solution to do this, as opposed to reinventing the wheel which may or may not work the first time.

What is the cleanest way to get a Google Blog-style header in my web page, preferably using CSS2 and jQuery for x-browser compatibility?

Edit - Bonus points if there's a way that doesn't require specifying heights to elements above the element to be scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating their css (more or less) with the placeholder, and then using some simple javascript results in a pretty smooth effect.

See http://jsfiddle.net/n9yPH/31/

The Jquery used is this:

```
$(function()
   {
       var start = $("#second").offset().top;
       $(window).scroll(function(e){
           var top = $("body").scrollTop();
           if (start-top >=0) $("#second").css("top",(start-top)+"px");
           else $("#second").css("top","0px");
       });
   });​
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for - is there a way to do this without specifying heights to the elements above #second?

Comment: You'd need to use javascript to set the `top` of `#second` on load, I think. I don't think there's a clean CSS way of getting it to default to where you want it, at an unknown position.

Comment: You can see an example of that here: [http://jsfiddle.net/n9yPH/34/](http://jsfiddle.net/n9yPH/34/)

Comment: I tried that using $("#first").height() instead of $("#third").offset().top, and it would never match up with pixel precision. The fiddle, however, does (how odd!). Methinks there needs to be some (light) refactoring in my CSS :D

Comment: I wonder if `.outerHeight()` or `.outerHeight(true)` would work? Maybe there's a margin or something that isn't being accounted for.

Comment: I tested it without margins, but with padding, and height() doesn't account for that - you'd have to use innerHeight(). Seems a bit counter-intuitive once you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution you would use the scroll event to determine the offset from the top and adjust elements in the DOM accordingly to "shrink" the header.